# Typescript unable to import fileReader

Tags: typescript

How do i import FileReader in typescript. I tried this:

```
var reader:FileReader = new FileReader();
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "out",
    "lib": [
        "es6"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "."
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode-test"
]
}
```

My error is cannot find name 'FileReader' I am unable to do this too:

```
import FileReader;
```

Comment: what file reader are you talking about?

Comment: you have to provide more info: your tsconfig.json, where is FileReader defined, it is a typescript or javascript class....

Comment: Standard FileReader (as present in JavaScript without libraries) is in **lib.d.ts** and you don't need to import anything. Check how old your lib.d.ts is. I think FileReader wasn't in lib.d.ts historicaly because lib.d.ts is exported from Internet Explorer and FileReader wasn't in older IE.

Comment: I tried using FileReader without import but im getting error cannot find name 'FileReader'

Comment: The FileReader API is defined in `lib.dom.d.ts` as seen here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3779 it should work without doing anything. If not, you can try to locate that file on your disk and use a triple-slash directive to force TypeScript to load it : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html but that would denote a flaw in your setup.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as I forgot to add "dom" to the "lib" node in the `tsconfig.json`.

Fix:

In your `tsconfig.json` ensure under "lib" you have "dom". Here is my current `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "dom",
         "dom.iterable",
         "esnext",
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

See the below ugly themed VS code the `lib.dom.d.ts` is where the `FileReader` interface lives which made me realise I was missing "dom"

[image]